# Error while installing 'Extension Pack for Java' extension. Please check the log for more details

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

**i am trying to install extension pack for java in visual studio but there is error, any one help me: ?**

2023-08-19 11:54:35.262 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 32ms
2023-08-19 11:54:48.979 [error] CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
at $t.download (/private/var/folders/t2/zymlcs150bzgl4k2d3y74n280000gn/T/AppTranslocation/CCA115C5-7461-4829-8B3B-2E0D8B7E81F4/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:92:141)
at async ee.y (/private/var/folders/t2/zymlcs150bzgl4k2d3y74n280000gn/T/AppTranslocation/CCA115C5-7461-4829-8B3B-2E0D8B7E81F4/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:92:20021)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4WUW.png)

I haven't done anything yet, and my wish is that I can install the extension pack for java

Comment: Sounds like a bad download; try downloading again.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Completely uninstall](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) vscode
2. Reinstall the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)

Or you can install [Coding Pack for Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_coding-pack-for-java)

[image]